# What is the purpose of the TestExecution class in MSTest?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest

I found the [TestExecution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testexecution.aspx) class, which exposes a bunch of events that would be incredibly helpful. However, I can't find a reference to it other than MSDN's documentation, and the documentation doesn't provide any hints as far as to how it is used, or how I might get a reference to an instance during a test run.

Looking with .NET Reflector wasn't helpful either - `TestExecution` is implemented by one other class, `UnitTestExecution`, which is internal. I could not find any other references to either class throughout any of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.* libraries, neither in the form of further implementations nor references as property types in any other classes.

How might I gain access to these events?

Comment: Looks like an abstract class so you likely have to derive from it and implement some abstract methods/properties.

Comment: Not necessarily ... I think it's more likely that the abstraction is used by the framework. Since it's a public class, and since UnitTestExecution isn't, it seems to follow the pattern of exposing the abstraction, but not the implementation. Usually, there's a way to get a reference to an instance of the abstraction (as with the TestContext property, where TestContext is also an abstract class), but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: This seems like one of those situations where "asking the author" would be best.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `TestExecution` instance is provided to you when implementing a custom `TestExtensionExecution`. It provides an [Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testextensionexecution.initialize.aspx) method, which you can override to subscribe to the test events.

This is usually part of an implementation of a custom test attribute in MSTest.

**Edit**
To create your own test extension, start with creating a new attribute that derives from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassExtensionAttribute`, which is an abstract class requiring you to provide a `TestExtensionExecution` via the `GetExtension()` method.

Apply your attribute to one of your test methods and you should be able to subscribe to those events during the test (inside your `TestExtensionExecution` implementation returned by the attribute)

Note that you also have to implement a `ITestMethodInvoker` which you should be able to create from the `TetMethodInvokerContext.TestMethodInfo` property supplied to the `TestExtensionExecute.CreateTestMethodInvoker` method.

Comment: How do you configure one of these extensions to be used?

Comment: I wish this information was already part of MSTest documentation on MSDN.